# How to get a local, older version of Safari on OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos, testing, safari

How to use an older version of Safari ( like Safari 5.1 or Safari 6.0 ) on Mac OS X Mavericks ? [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965222/how-can-i-test-my-website-in-an-old-version-of-safari-on-os-x) answers my question for OS X, except Mavericks.

Multi-Safari website doesn't load and from a google cached copy I only saw Mac OS X Lion solutions.

I'd prefer a local solution instead of using services like BrowserStack because they're just annoyingly slow...

Comment: Looking for the same thing. Haven't found a way ether.

Comment: The Multi-Safari website loads for me -- http://michelf.ca/projects/multi-safari/ -- but none of the versions run on Mavericks.

Comment: FYI version `4.0.5` works on Mavericks

Answer (score 1):

CNET has outdated Safari versions for download, e.g.

- [5.1.7](http://download.cnet.com/Apple-Safari/3000-2356_4-10697481.html) , found via [this search for Safari 6](http://download.cnet.com/s/safari-6/)
- [8.0.6](http://download.cnet.com/Apple-Safari/3000-2356_4-34119.html)

That said, I couldn't actually install them -- running the installer seems to succeed, but nothing new appears in /Applications, and OSX won't let you delete Safari as it's "required by OSX".

Answer (score -1):

Try to search specific build in http://nightly.webkit.org/builds/trunk/mac/1.

Comment: Will not work, per Multi-Safari website: "Safari normally uses the Web Kit framework found inside Mac OS X to render web pages and execute javascript. This means that if you preserve an old version of Safari to run it on a newer version of Mac OS, it will use the newer Web Kit found in the system and you will get the same results as with the newer version. Thus, you would normally need a separate installation of Mac OS X for each version of Safari you want to test a website into."